# Tensorflow custom loss function with additional data

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am modelling a large dataset via tensorflow and a NN but I need to implement a custom loss function to give weight to the binary outcome. The weights are part of the original dataset but stripped out of the modelling as they themselves would bias the results. How can I pass these weights so they can be used in the loss function? If i leave them in the y dataframe I get errors in the model as its expecting output shape of 1 but if i set the output to 2 then it will try to predict the cweight.

```
def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    loss = 1
    """
        pseudo code:
        
        if y_pred > 0.5:
            if y_true == 1:
                loss = w["cweight"]*-1
            else:
                loss = 1
        else:
            if y_true == 0:
                loss = w["cweight"]*-1
            else:
                loss = 1

        basically if correct prediction then multiply by the cweight*-1
        otherwise loss is 1
    """    
    
    return loss


exampledata = pd.DataFrame([{"a":1.0,"b":0,"c":0.1,"result":1,"cweight":0.1},
                            {"a":0.8,"b":1,"c":0.5,"result":0,"cweight":0.5},
                            {"a":0.5,"b":1,"c":0.6,"result":0,"cweight":0.5},
                            {"a":0.2,"b":1,"c":0.9,"result":1,"cweight":0.3}])

x = exampledata[["a","b","c"]]
y = exampledata["result"]
w = exampledata[["result","cweight"]]



model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(256 , input_shape=(3,), activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(256 , activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=custom_loss,metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=5)
#real code has train/text/validate etc
```

I tried leaving cweight in the y dataframe but that gives an error in the output layer.

Comment: Your loss does not look like a differentiable function.

Comment: sorry probably not making it clear. so i want to weight the predictions as follows:

loss = y_pred * y_true * cweights*-1

so only a predicted and true value of 1 would be weighted and all other outcomes would be close to 0

Comment: `loss` function must be a differentiable function of `y_pred`. Your function is a piecewise constant function taking values either `1` or `w["cweight"]*-1`. The derivative is either 0 or infinity. If you need a weighted loss you have to define the differentiable `loss` first and than multiply on your weights somehow.